# Why do I get Arithmetic overflow when :(Int64)(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16.MaxValue+1);

Tags: c#, .net, overflow, int64

What do I overlook in the expression below? Does not Int64 type has larger range than Int16?

```
Int64 value = (Int64)(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16.MaxValue+1);
```

System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16.MaxValue is 32767.
Int64.MaxValue() is 9223372036854775807.

32767 + 1 = 32768. And that is much(!) lower than 9223372036854775807.

So why do I get Aritmethic Overflow when I cast

```
(Int64)(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16.MaxValue+1);
```

to Int64?

(Is it something to do with the implementation of + operator in C# or...?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqlTypes.SqlInt16 is an interesting type.  It *looks* like a *short?* but it is not, it is actually a *struct*.  It has a bunch of operator overloads that makes it behave like a number.  Do note how this version works just fine:

```
    Int64 value = (Int64)(short.MaxValue + 1);    // okay
```

Which uses the "normal" addition operator, it can never overflow since the CLR doesn't actually have a addition operator that works for *short*.  The nearest type it supports is Int32, that doesn't overflow here.

But SqlInt16 was written to catch this mistake, it has an `operator+()` overload, it was explicitly written to generate this exception.  In other words, it *does* implement the semantics of a 16-bit addition and yells when the result doesn't fit back into a dbase table column of a 16-bit integral type.  Regardless whether you use the *checked* or *unchecked* keywords in C#.  Which is a Good Thing, you really want to know about that when you work with a dbase.

You need to invoke another method of SqlInt16, a *conversion* operator.  The one that converts SqlInt16 to a native integral type.  The tongue-in-cheek variety looks like this:

```
   Int64 value = (Int64)((short)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16.MaxValue + 1);
```

But of course it makes more sense to cast to Int64 directly, SqlInt16 has a conversion operator for that one too:

```
   Int64 value = (Int64)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16.MaxValue + 1;
```

Do beware the iffy semantics of code like this.  You can't cast a dbase column.  My first snippet makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to cast the result ot `SqlInt16.MaxValue+1` to an `Int64`. But `SqlInt16.MaxValue` is a `SqlInt16`. Adding +1 to that will overflow before you even cast it.

---

What you want to do is first cast the `SqlInt16.MaxValue` to `Int64` and then add `1` to it:

```
Int64 value = (Int64)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16.MaxValue + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead, you're trying to add 1 to the max value of `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16`

```
Int64 value = (Int64)(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16.MaxValue) +1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16.MaxValue+1)` is an `int16` - or *trying* to be at least, which is invalid.

Just cast the `MaxValue` to `int64` first, then add 1 afterwards.

Just to examplify this:

```
var x = (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16.MaxValue + 0);
var t = x.GetType(); // t will be System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16
```

Answer (score 0):

Hover your mouse over the `+` sign in your code, and you will get a tool tip popping up telling you it (overload resolution) goes to a "user-defined" operator. Choose "Go to definition" or F12 on that `+` character, and you will see the signature:

```
public static SqlInt16 operator +(SqlInt16 x, SqlInt16 y);
```

([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlint16.op_addition.aspx))

So you now know that the right-hand operand `1` is implicitly converted to `SqlInt16` (first converted implicitly from `int` to `short` via C#'s rules for constant (literal) expression conversions, then converted from `short` to `SqlInt16` via a "user-defined" `implicit operator`). Then we have two `SqlInt16` values. The `operator` above takes them in and wants to return a third `SqlInt16` value, their sum. But that is impossible. The exception arises.

So we never get to your cast to `Int64`; the problem occurs before that.

To fix it, explicitly convert `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16.MaxValue` to e.g. `Int64` (a.k.a. `long`) or `Int16` (a.k.a. `short`) ***before*** the addition (`+`).

Of course, you can also use:

```
long value = short.MaxValue + 1;
```

because `short.MaxValue` has the same numerical value as `SqlInt16.MaxValue`, but I don't know if you can use this in your application.